Computing $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(xy^n+x^ny,xy)]$ and similar extensions
The following three questions are similar to this question.
For every natural numbers $k,l,m,n \geq 2$, define:

$A_{n}=\mathbb{C}(xy^n+x^ny,xy)$.

$B_{m,n}=\mathbb{C}(xy^m+x^my,xy^n+x^ny)$, in addition, $m \neq n$.

$C_{k,l,m,n}=\mathbb{C}(xy^k+x^ly,xy^m+x^ny)$, in addition, $k \neq l$ and $m \neq n$.


Question: What are the degrees of the field extensions
$[\mathbb{C}(x,y):A_n]$, $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):B_{m,n}]$, $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):C_{k,l,m,n}]$?
For $A_2=\mathbb{C}(xy^2+x^2y,xy)$, we see that $xy^2+x^2y=xy(x+y)$, so $x+y \in A_2$,
hence $S_{\alpha}=\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy) \subseteq A_2$, so $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):A_2]=2$,
where $S_{\alpha}$ ia the set of symmetric elements w.r.t. the exchange involution $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$. (It is clear that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):A_2]\neq 1$, since, for example, $y \notin A_2$).
Claim: $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):A_n]=n$.
Attempt of proof: Let us first consider $n=3$. $A_3=\mathbb{C}(xy^3+x^3y,xy)$, we see that $xy^3+x^3y=xy(x^2+y^2)$, so $x^2+y^2 \in A_3$,
hence $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy \in A_3$, then I do not know how to continue.
Actually for $A_4$: $xy^4+x^4y=xy(x^3+y^3) \in A_4$, so $x^3+y^3 \in A_4$, then $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3(x^2y+xy^2)$, so perhaps $(x+y)^3 \notin A_4$.
Any hints are welcome, thank you!

Write $A_n=\mathbb C(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}, xy)$, we have $\mathbb C(x,y)=A_n(x)$, and $x$ satisfies the polynomial:
$$T^{2(n-1)}-(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1})T^{n-1}+(xy)^{n-1}$$
Therefore $[\mathbb C(x,y):A_n]\le 2(n-1)$. For each $(n-1)$-th root of unity $\zeta$, we have both $\begin{cases} x\mapsto \zeta x \\ y\mapsto \frac{1}{\zeta} y\end{cases}$ and $\begin{cases}x\mapsto \zeta y \\ y\mapsto \frac{1}{\zeta}x \end{cases}$ are in $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C(x,y)|A_n)$. Therefore $[\mathbb C(x,y):A_n]\ge 2(n-1)$. In all, $[\mathbb C(x,y):A_n]=2(n-1)$. In fact, we can even compute $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C(x,y)|A_n)\simeq D_{n-1}$. (c.f. my answer for a similar question.)
I don't know how to handle $B_{m, n}, C_{m, n, l}$ yet. But I don't feel the answer is easy, may not even have closed form. One idea might be to compute the degree $[S:B_{m,n}]$, where $S$ is the space of symmetric fractions of $x, y$, as we know $[\mathbb C(x,y):S]=2$.

Thank you very much! The computation is nice. Please, it seems that you computed a different degree than the one in the question, but the degree you computed is also interesting to me. Is there a conncetion between those two degrees?

@user237522 Your claim is false, but it happens that when $n=2$, $2(n-1)=n$. In the case $n=3$, you have shown that $(x+y)^2\in A_3$, therefore $[S_{\alpha}:A_3]\le 2$, and then $[\mathbb C(\alpha,\beta):A_3]\le 2\cdot 2 =4=2(n-1)$, and it can be shown equality holds using Galois group.

Thank you for your comment.

Your $A_n=\mathbb{C}(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1},xy)=R_1$ is exactly my $A_n=\mathbb{C}(xy^n+x^ny,xy)=R_2$. Indeed, $(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1})xy=x^ny+xy^n \in R_2$ and $(\frac{1}{xy})(xy^n+x^ny)=y^{n-1}+x^{n-1} \in R_1$. That's what I have not seen a few days ago.

I have now asked an 'opposite' question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4939682/finding-mathbbcu-v-such-that-mathbbcu-v-xpyp-mathbbcx-y-f
