Finding $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ such that $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^p+y^p)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, for every prime number $p$ or $p=1$
Denote the set of prime numbers by $P$, $P=\{2,3,5,7,\ldots\}$.
Let $F \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and for $w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ denote by $F(w)$ the subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ generated by $F$ and $w$.
Assume that $F$ satisfies the following three properties:
(p1) $F=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ with $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
(p2) For every $p \in P$, $F(x^p+y^p)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
(p3) $F(x+y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Question: Is it true that for such $F$ necessarily $x \in F$ or $y \in F$? If not, is there something interesting that can be said about $F$?

For example: Take $F=\mathbb{C}(xf,y)$, where $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\gcd(f,x)=1$. $F$ satisfies the three properties; indeed, for every $n \in \{1\} \cup P$, $F(x^n+y^n)=\mathbb{C}(xf,y,x^n+y^n)=\mathbb{C}(xf,y,x^n)$. By the result presented here, $\mathbb{C}(xf,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x)$ (because $\langle xf,x^n \rangle = \langle x \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$, by our choice of $f$), so $F(x^n+y^n)=\mathbb{C}(xf,x^n,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

But maybe there are examples of $F$ such that $x \notin F$ and $y \notin F$?

Remarks:

An 'opposite' question is this question, in which $x^n+y^n$ is already in the subfield, for some fixed $n$, not a generator. Here $x^n+y^n$ are generators for prime numbers $n$ or $n=1$.

Now posted here.


Thank you very much!
